# Why ActiveRecord::Base.connected? is false, after calling establish_connection

Tags: ruby, testing, activerecord

I develop Sinatra application and use there ActiveRecord for working with database, but I encountered one problem. I wrote a test for a model and it breaks with

> SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file

Connection to database is established in test_helper.rb with the following code:

```
Dir.chdir('..') do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)
end
```

and `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` get false. If I call `User.find(:all)` for example after connection establishment test will pass and `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` will be true. Why? I don't understand.

Comment: As I understand establish_connection does not do real connection. So the question is, when the connection to database is really established?

Comment: Connection is really established after the first call of model method. My problem was in path to database. In configuration file path is relative, test was run from directory, where database file cannot be accessed by relative path. Changing path to absolute in test_helper.rb solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` only sets up the connection and ActiveRecord does not actually connect until a connection to the database is requested.
The following code may help you force ActiveRecord to establish a connection for the connection-pool:

```
connected = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { |con| con.active? }  rescue false
```

The `rescue false` hides a couple of potential exceptions (eg. `PG::ConnectionBad`).
Refer to the [documentation of :with_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-with_connection) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection is delegated to ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler#stablish_connection and if you take a look at its [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L501) you'll see that it just creates a connection pull

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and run `rake db:create` for your test environment. It looks as though the DB does not exist and in SQLite that should be dependent on the directory.